# asp.net is a compiled language?

Tags: asp.net

The reason for my question is that in my work we use asp.net with vb.net , I really had never used alone c # to Desktop and PHP for web, they say that ASP.NET is a programming language compiled , but we do changes the production environment and do not have to compile anything , example I make a page called profile.aspx with their respective profile.aspc.vb and they only go up and nothing happens, if the language is compiled, should not I compile in visual studio and give me some kind of file where you can not see the source code ?

Comment: view are not *normally* compiled. and .vb files are not part of the files used by the server so it doesn't care if you upload it or not. the compiled files are .dll on your bin folder.

Comment: No, they don't say "ASP.NET is a programming language compiled" because ASP.NET isn't a language. Perhaps you're talking about Web Forms pages (.aspx) and user controls (.ascx)?

Comment: This question is far too broad, because you don't know enough to ask a good question.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio when you run application by pressing F5 it will not generate final version as it is debug mode.

If you want that your code should not be visible to anyone then you have to publish your application and this time it will generate compiled file (.dll) and your aspx page  directive will change from codebehind to class ( Class name from compiled dll)

Two thing you have to take care in publish

1. Publish with allow update : This time when you look at publish Default.aspx ( any aspx)then you will find all markup in aspx file and content as well so you can update that part in production directly.
2. Another option is not allow undate : This time when you look at Default.aspx (any aspx) then it does not contain anything and this time aspx also compiled to DLL.

Hope this help you to understand.